# Message is not defined using "messageReactionAdd" event to perform action

Tags: javascript, discord.js, member

I want my bot to perform an action to "message.member" when this very member react with a certain emoji to the message from my bot. However, I have an error "message is not defined" and I can't do anything with it.

I think I need to use "messageReactionAdd" because I need to know every reactions on my server, check them if they are applied to my bot's message, then return an action to the user that did them. This must concern all message from my bot, even old ones. All methods I want to use are
GuildMember's methods : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember.

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  console.log(`mess id : ${reaction.message.id} emoji user = ${reaction.message.member.id}`);
    if ((reaction.message.author.id == client.user.id) && (user.id != client.user.id)) {
      if (reaction.emoji.name == '') {
        message.member.send('You picked   '); 
      }
    }
  });
```

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Client.client.on (/home/me/botdiscord/index.js:84:7)
    at Client.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at MessageReactionAdd.handle (/home/me/botdiscord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageReactionAdd.js:46:17)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD] (/home/me/botdiscord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD.js:4:37)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/me/botdiscord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/me/botdiscord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/me/botdiscord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/me/botdiscord/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/me/botdiscord/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:797:20)
(node:7306) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7306) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```js
message.member.send('You picked   ');
```

`message` is not defined. Instead, use [`reaction.message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=message)

Comment: "message.member.send('You picked   '); " is the bot

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

`Message` is not defined in your code. And most likely, the author of the message is the bot, so you would try to send a message to the bot. As you can see you're getting a `User` object as the second parameter. You can use the `send()` method of `User` to send a message to the user.

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  console.log(`mess id : ${reaction.message.id} emoji user = ${reaction.message.member.id}`);
    if ((reaction.message.author.id == client.user.id) && (user.id != client.user.id)) {
      if (reaction.emoji.name == '') {
        user.send('You picked '); 
      }
    }
  });
```

Note: Depending on the user's privacy settings, your code may fail. Use a `.catch` block to catch any errors and preventing the bot from crashing.

Comment: I have an error :

`
(node:15594) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/me/botdiscord/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
`

Comment: @FomaFomitch I've updated my code. I misunderstood your question. Also, please read the note I've put.

Answer (score 0):

I did add "reaction.message[...]" but can't see the message. So I put the ".nickname" method to see if it works. But my change nickname to himself, and not to the user that did the emohi reaction. Any help with this please ?

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  console.log(`mess id : ${reaction.message.id} emoji user = ${reaction.message.member.id}`);
    if ((reaction.message.author.id == client.user.id) && (user.id != client.user.id)) {
      if (reaction.emoji.name == '') {
        reaction.message.member.setNickname('')
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: `reaction.message.member` will return the `GuildMember` object of whoever sent the message being reacted to. To get the `GuildMember` object of whoever reacted, use: `reaction.message.guild.member(user)`